# Selenium send_keys with no response

Tags: python, html, selenium, phantomjs

When I run my code with PhantomJS and selenium ,and the res shows act, but in send_keys the code won't go on, just stay in, no wrong , no any answer and no keep in. I just want know why.

```
res = re.findall(r'\<input id=\"([^\n]*)\" type=\"file\" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;',pages)
dr = driver.find_element_by_id(res[0])
dr.send_keys('/Users/liangshengjun/Desktop/bin/2_0.jpg')
```

Comment: Why do you use regular expression instead of `css` selector or `xpath`? share `HTML` for your `input` element

Comment: Because I didn't have learned css, and the path was dynamic.so I choice re.

Comment: try `dr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]')`, then `dr.send_keys('/Users/liangshengjun/Desktop/bin/2_0.jpg')`, then `dr.submit()`

Comment: thank you very much, that I learn a better way to find path. but the program also no response just black...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you've only selected file, you don't submit any form and didn't take any action. So you need either to click some submit button or send ENTER key with your file path like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# your code here, then add this key on last step.
dr.send_keys('/Users/liangshengjun/Desktop/bin/2_0.jpg' + Keys.ENTER)
```

And you really shouldn't use regexes to find an input, you'd better try xpath or may be css selectors.

And it's good approach to debug with some graphic browser like Firefox before switching to headless mode (Google Chrome --headless or PhantomJS as in your case).

Comment: thank you. but I get a rise:  Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers": ... \"/Users/liangshengjun/Desktop/bin/2_0.jpg\\ue007\", \"value\": [\"/\", \"U\", \"s\", \"e\", \"r\", \"s\", \"/\", \"l\", \"i\", \"a\", \"n\", \"g\", \"s\", \"h\", \"e\", \"n\", \"g\", \"j\", \"u\", \"n\", \"/\", \"D\", \"e\", \"s\", \"k\", \"t\", \"o\", \"p\", \"/\", \"b\", \"i\", \"n\", \"/\", \"2\", \"_\", \"0\", \".\", \"j\", \"p\", \"g\", \"\\ue007\"], \"id\": \":wdc:1499537747792\", \"sessionId\": \"7500f610-6409-11

Comment: And I also want to know the message ,send by selenium ,from serve or selenium?

Comment: It might be something with a value you've entered into input field. Or it might be well known PhantomJS bug, check this thread: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11637. I really suggest you to try Firefox first in order to check interactions with your eyes.

Comment: thank you! I want to try Firefox in my next case or my free time . But I need submit my case tomorrow. So I thought , maybe I need find something in page source , maybe a js was doing something. anyway ,thank you very much.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you. So people can google it easier.

Comment: May I ask you for help me read the source of page?  I can't understand the html code.                     '<input id="alisearch-keywords" class="empty" accesskey="s" autocomplete="off" name="keywords" placeholder="粘贴淘宝商品链接，看同款货源">
                    <span id="sm-widget-picbtn" class="sm-widget-picbtn" style="z-index: 1;"></span><button type="button" id="alisearch-submit" data-spm-click="gostr=/1688hjlj;locaid=ds6">搜 索</button> <div id="sm-widget-upload" class="sm-widget-upload">'

Comment: <span class="upload-1688"></span><span class="upload-txt">正在上传图片，请稍后...</span><div id="html5_1bkhpg8nn2hg5oa1bco1jfj2p03_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 71px; left: 585px; width: 40px; height: 38px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1bkhpg8nn2hg5oa1bco1jfj2p03" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp"></div></div>.   that's all. I want send image to input id="html5 ... the input seems weard.